# Combining two graphs in python, but graphs don't show up

Tags: python, graph

hope someone can help have a look of what's wrong with the code. I want to combine a bar graph and a line graph, they all work seperately, but I can see anything once I combine them.
Here's the code:

```
import seaborn as sb
sales = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Create combo chart
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
color = 'tab:green'
#bar plot creation
ax1.set_title('Trend of Sales and Profit', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_xlabel('Order Year', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel('Sales', fontsize=16)
ax1 = sb.barplot(x='Order Year', y='Sales',hue='Order Quarter', ci=None, data = sales, palette='summer')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
ax1.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))

#specify we want to share the same x-axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
color = 'tab:red'
#line plot creation
ax2.set_ylabel('Profit %', fontsize=16)
ax2 = sb.lineplot(x='Order Year', y='Profit',ci=None, data = sales, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', color=color)
```

Here's what I get 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikFkW.png)

Would really appreciate it if anyone can have a look. Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like some of your code is not shown here... can't find the name sb anywhere and your plot is not entirely blank which suggests you're at least setting x or y limits or something...

Answer (score 0):

You're reassigning `ax1` to `sb.barplot`.
So you lose your handle to the actual axes in the figure. Which is why your plot is blank.
`ax1.bar(<args>)`
is what you want.

You're doing the same thing with `ax2`, and thus all subsequent data is appended to figures that aren't part of your `fig`.

Well, that's what I can tell without knowing where `sb` comes from...

Comment: hey many thanks for the reply. Sb stands for seaborn, so basically I want to create two graphs with same x axis and different y axis, then use twinx() to put them in the same plot. Both of the graphs work fine in speperate, but once I combine them the graph is empty.

Comment: Ok, so what does your code look like when it's one graph? Because you're still reassigning ax1 to the output of sb.barplot... that's never going to work. Show us what you got working with the single chart.